# Redirect command line results to a texture (html) in real time

Tags: python, html, subprocess

I would run a server and view real-time results in a textarea on a html page. Is it possible? For now I get to do it when the command is finished, but I would like to do while the server is running.

I tried:

```
r = subprocess.Popen(argServer, shell=True, stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT, close_fds=True)
stdout, stderr = r.communicate()
print """<textarea>""" + stdout + """</textarea>"""
```

but it does not work

Comment: What is `argServer`?

Comment: With this style ? Sorry can't. Create threaded socket server(multi,every signal an external thread), use Jquery-Ajax or Ajax query for pushing text(Client send query and close browser, how to end your thread). All app need be in same app(os level access got large delay). I got 0.98ms delay (query+answer+show) with related things(packet size : 3.5kb).

Comment: argServer is the command (the server)